# django many-to-many field admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a many-to-many field between two models in Django. I however only see a form field in one of the models on the admin page. I tried adding a many-to-many field in the second model, and although this added a form field in the admin page, the two form fields were not synchronized (so changing the value on one form field doesn't affect the other one). Is there a way to have a many-to-many relationship and have two form fields in the admin page and both are synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source Django app called django-admin-extend which addresses the issue of bidirectional many-to-many fields using add_bidirectional_m2m and _get_bidirectional_m2m_fields. It can be installed via pip.

https://github.com/kux/django-admin-extend

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-extend

Answer (score 0):

If you define the m2m relationship in both models, and set the "through" attribute of one to be equal to the "through" of the other, you get access to the m2m relationship from both sides, and get to see it from both admin pages.

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    tests2 = models.ManyToManyField('Test2', blank=True)

class Test2(models.Model):
    tests1 = models.ManyToManyField('Test1', through=Test1.tests2.through, blank=True)
```

as seen in https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/897

Comment: The current versions of Django explicitly [disallow](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12203) many to many fields that manually specify a relationship model (i.e. use the `through` parameter) from being displayed within the admin interface.